# Does an AWS Lambda keep field values throughout its invocation?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Imagine the following java code:

```
public class HandlerClass implements RequestHandler<DynamodbEvent, int> {

    int i = 0;

    public RequestHandler() {}

    public int handleRequest(DynamodbEvent dynamodbEvent, Context context) {
        i = i + 1;
        System.out.println(i);
        return i
    }
}
```

Now the lambda is triggered from an DynamoDB event A, which would lead to an invocation of the lambda, which in turn would create an instance of the RequestHandler class and a call to handleRequest().
Shortly after event A was handled, but before the timeout of the lambda, event B fires.

Does event B reuse the same instance of the RequestHandler class and thus would print "2" or does event B receive its own instance and prints "1"?

What would happen if i was static?

Comment: Why not try it out? Put a log statement in the c'tor and run it. Then change the field to a static field, put a log statement in a `static { ... }` block and run it.

Comment: Also read: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50347544/4800344

Comment: If you need to keep values across multiple invocations - store them in a database like DynamoDB

Comment: What do you mean by "the timeout of the lambda" when you say "Shortly after event A was handled, but before the timeout of the lambda, event B fires"?

Comment: @smac2020
I explicitly don't want that. I was interested if the values would be kept without my knowledge.

Comment: @jarmod It is my understanding that a lambda is initiated, has multiple invocations and after a period without any usage is being shut down. I wanted to know if field values of my handler class are being stored throughout multiple invocations. But Leeroy answered my question.

Comment: OK, just wanted to clarify. The term "timeout" has a specific meaning in AWS Lambda functions and relates to the maximum time that a single invocation of the function will be allowed to run before it is failed by the Lambda runtime. You're referring to the execution environment itself being [shutdown](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtime-environment.html#runtimes-lifecycle-shutdown).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the request handler is not shared across invocations, but objects initiated outside of the request handler is.

The answer is `1`

For that reason it's always best practices to create your reusable components outside of the request handler to save you having to initiate them on each invocation.